# Get information from data PHP

Tags: php

I have no idea even what this is called so had no idea what to search for. I do apologise if this already exists.

I have information that I can get from going to a specific URL. It displays with something that looks like this:

```
 {"loading":false,"playing":true,"position":5730,"duration":211875,"index":0,"repeat":false,"shuffle":false,"volume":1,"context":null,"contexts":[],"track":{"artists":[{"name":"R3hab","uri":"spotify:artist:6cEuCEZu7PAE9ZSzLLc2oQ"},{"name":"Vinai","uri":"spotify:artist:4mrBetqy378Jf1y6NLszlx"}],"disc":0,"duration":212000,"image":"spotify:image:9ab80608da23ad97a5fd1cd8285f7a9239169c9d","images":[[64,"spotify:image:544aab2c02ea3ece23145ac3fdb78649e1181cad"],[300,"spotify:image:9ab80608da23ad97a5fd1cd8285f7a9239169c9d"],[600,"spotify:image:8537cde9090567164f449b25c00ad0c40e5c7325"]],"name":"How We Party - Original Mix","number":1,"playable":true,"popularity":67,"starred":false,"explicit":false,"availability":"premium","album":{"uri":"spotify:album:2IhQHv3MS8iq26We33dLdQ"},"local":false,"advertisement":false,"placeholder":false,"uri":"spotify:track:2b0N6oW4f87wNr9uahicc2"}}
```

If you scroll half through you'll see:

```
"name":"How We Party - Original Mix
```

I need a PHP script that would find the name of the track and displays it like this:

```
How We Party - Original Mix
```

Beware that the code has the word "name" in it several times i.e. name of album, which I don't need. The position of order is always the same so that may help.

I have no idea how to even start going about this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The data structure you found is a *JSON object*. Use that as search term, and you will learn how to process them with PHP. (It's not that hard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string is JSON. To parse it you would use `json_decode()`. Then you can access it like an object (or an array if you pass `true` as the second parameter).

```
$str = '{"loading":false,"playing":true,"position":5730,"duration":211875,"index":0,"repeat":false,"shuffle":false,"volume":1,"context":null,"contexts":[],"track":{"artists":[{"name":"R3hab","uri":"spotify:artist:6cEuCEZu7PAE9ZSzLLc2oQ"},{"name":"Vinai","uri":"spotify:artist:4mrBetqy378Jf1y6NLszlx"}],"disc":0,"duration":212000,"image":"spotify:image:9ab80608da23ad97a5fd1cd8285f7a9239169c9d","images":[[64,"spotify:image:544aab2c02ea3ece23145ac3fdb78649e1181cad"],[300,"spotify:image:9ab80608da23ad97a5fd1cd8285f7a9239169c9d"],[600,"spotify:image:8537cde9090567164f449b25c00ad0c40e5c7325"]],"name":"How We Party - Original Mix","number":1,"playable":true,"popularity":67,"starred":false,"explicit":false,"availability":"premium","album":{"uri":"spotify:album:2IhQHv3MS8iq26We33dLdQ"},"local":false,"advertisement":false,"placeholder":false,"uri":"spotify:track:2b0N6oW4f87wNr9uahicc2"}}';

// object
$obj = json_decode($str);
echo $obj->track->name;

// array
$obj = json_decode($str, true);
echo $obj['track']['name'];
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/194277)

Comment: I am definitely going to have to start and implement a DEMO button in my answers ;)